# DS3231 High Power Consumption

Tags: power, ds3231-alarms

I plan to use my Arduino with a small battery all the time so I don't want it to use so much power. I was checking power consumption of DS3231 with a multimeter, at first it was fluttering around 1 mA and 0.4 mA with 3.3 volts. I removed the battery on DS3231 to reduce affect of charging but now it's still high, about 0.4 mA. The official paper says it should use a lot lower than that. Is it an error about my multimeter or is there something I missed like a configuration or something?

[image]

Comment: I think the data sheet talks about the current consumption from the battery. That mean, how much the module draws from the battery if it not connected to a controller. If it is connected to a controller and communicates with it, it needs more current which it draws from the controller. and not from it's own buffer battery.

Comment: Yes I connected its power to a digital pin now.